# fopen fails with EFBIG "File too large" after creating a lot of files

Tags: c++, linux, error-handling, filesystems, limit

i am creating a program that creates small files(8 kb) based on some input so it goes like this

```
#include <iostream>
#incclude <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

void func()
{
    const char * file_name = NULL;
    // we get file_name from somewhere , ex : pic.png
    FILE * fp = fopen();
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
       std::cout << "failed to open file , " << strerror(errno) << std::endl ;
       return 0;
    }
     // some code to deal with the file
}
```

i created a lot of files (about 4.2 Million , i am trying to test the performance)
and it always about at the same number makes an error of EFBIG (File too large)
although i am creating new unique file each time.

the files are created in 8 threads .

any idea about an explanation for that ?

i want to clarify that obviously this is not the exact code , but you can think this function run in 8 threads with high frequency until that error is generated, also this error is generated for all files from that point until the program finishes

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213817/discussion-on-question-by-waleed-osama-fopen-fails-with-efbig-file-too-large-a).

Answer (score 2):

I can't actually find this documented for Linux anywhere, but since your number of files has apparently hit the maximum 32-bit unsigned integer (4,294,967,295), it sounds like your filesystem cannot handle more than this many files in a single directory. The error "too big" really refers to the directory, not the file you're trying to open.

That's a crazy number of files in a single directory. Just split them into different directories.

Also, be careful not to keep gazillions of file handles open at one time; your OS will emplace a limit on that (which you can check with `ulimit -a`). However, you're supposed to get `EMFILE` when you exhaust this supply.